# Centos 6 Timezone Wrong

Tags: centos, timezone, date

I am trying to set my Centos 6 VPS to GMT timezone.

I tried a `sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime`

Which works fine.

However when I run `date` it returns:

> Tue Oct  4 05:09:32 GMT 2016

Which indicates there is something that is much more of a problem.

Googling `GMT time` returns `16:57`...

How come this is happening?

Comment: how can I fix the clock time? @yoonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by contacting my host and asking them to fix and set the clock time on their node.

If your on a dedicated server you can do this yourself by issuing:

```
# date -s "4 OCT 2016 18:00:00"
```

as root